# Spring Boot Data Source not creating JNDI

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, jndi

Application.yml -

```
spring:
  profiles: desktop

  datasource:
    db:
      url : jdbc:xxxx
      username : xxxx
      password : xxxx
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      jndi-name: jndiName
      tomcat:
        max-wait : 20000
        max-active : 5
        max-idle : 2
        min-idle : 2
```

Application.java -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    private YAMLConfig myConfig;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Running application");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

DBConfig.java -

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "dbTransactionManager", basePackages = { "com.et.repo" })
public class DBConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "ldbDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.db")
    public DataSource dbDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dbEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dbDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.et.entity").persistenceUnit("db").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dbTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager dbTransactionManager(@Qualifier("dbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

I was expecting this configuration to create a JNDI with name "jndiName", but doesn't seem to be creating it. This code shows nothing -

```
context = new InitialContext();
log.info("Listing JNDI's");
NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list = context.list("");
while (list.hasMore()) {
  log.info("Name: " + list.next().getName());
}
```

What am I missing? I read somewhere that naming is not enabled by default in embedded Tomcat. Could that be it? How do I enable it with this configuration ?

Comment: Do you want to take a look at this?? 
https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jndi-datasource-example/

Comment: Thanks, Anand. Though that is not exactly what I am looking for, it makes sense. I think I have to think differently on this one. I somehow assumed that a JNDI will be created from my configuration. I just learned that jndi-name is for loading a JNDI that is already created. Seems I have to figure out a way to create the JNDI on start up. That leads me back to the article you referred to.

Comment: Welcome. Hope you manage to solve your problem :)